# 1080p External Monitor through a Dell XPS 15 L502X?

Tags: dell, nvidia-optimus

Did someone succeed using an external monitor through the HDMI or Mini DisplayPort of the Dell XPS 15 L502X under Ubuntu 11.10. IF so can you please tell me what you did?

The Discrete graphics card is a Nvidia GT525M 1 Go.
The CPU is an Intel i7 2670QM with Turbo Boost.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, using a mini DisplayPort to DVI ou HDMI adapter and connecting the External Monitor through it, is working fine. and you get full 1080p resolution.

While HDMI port does not on DELL XPS 15, as it is optimus based.

Installing Bumblebee project or Ironhide enbales Optimus and the use of the Nvidia card but HDMI support is still in the laboratory.

One can enable the HDMI video output under a native resolution (supposing that one installed bumblebee), on terminal:

```
$ optirun nvidia-settings -c :8

$ DISPLAY=:8 firefox
```

Check this to enable the HDMI port with native resolution:
https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/67

**UPDATE:** Check the new support for Optimus in Ubuntu 13.04, named REVERSE PRIME (Only Nouveau)